# SQL - Is there a better way to handle many transactions on one table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

So say you have a single SQL table in some relation DB (SQL Server, MySQL, whatever). Say you have 500 tasks that runs every 15mins. Each task will delete a portion of data related to that task, insert new data related to that task then an external source will some selects for data related to that task.

From my experience this inevitably leads to deadlocks, timeouts and all around sub-par performance for selects, even when doing dirty reads.

You can try to stagger the start time of the tasks as best you can but it doesn't really solve the issue. There are so many tasks that there will always be overlap.

You can try upgrading the server with a better CPU to handle the connections but this is very costly for just 500 tasks imo.

So what I've done is duplicated the tables Schema and gave every task it's own distinct table with that schema. 
Also, when constructing new data for the table all it does is inserts into a new table then flips the name of current table with that one.

ie

CREATE TABLE Task001_Table_Inactive

Bulk insert the fresh data to Task001_Table_Inactive

DROP TABLE Task001_Table_Active

RENAME Task001_Table_Inactive Task001_Table_Active

The advantages:

-Fast processing. SQL has NEVER been good at constant deletes. The ability to just bulk insert and flips the name has drastically reduced the processing time for the task.

-Scalable. Now that all these inserts and deletes aren't constantly fighting over one table I can run many tasks on one very cheap machine in the cloud.

-Anti-fragmentation. Since the table is recreated every time, any fragmentation issues that plague systems with constant deletes is no longer an issue.

-Selects are as quick as possible WITH OUT the need for dirty reads. Since the insertion is done in separate table the select statements being done by the external source will be as quick as it can be with out the need to do a dirty read. This is the biggest advantage imo!

-Fast migrations. Eventually I'll have too many tasks and run out of processing power, even with this setup. So if I need to migrate a task to a different server it's a simple matter of copying two tables rather than a hacky and extremely slow select statement on a blob table...

-Indexability. When a tables gets too big (300mill rows +) you can not index it. No matter what it'll just chug for a few days and give up because of a transaction buffer limit. This is just how SQL is. By segmenting out the huge blob table into smaller tables you can index successfully. Take this combined with parallelization, and you can index all the data FASTER than if you were doing indexing on a big table.

Disadvantages:

-Makes navigation of tables in a GUI difficult

-Makes select / schema alter statements slightly tricky because now it has to do some sort of cursor over each table like %*Table*% and apply the SQL command to each.

So why do many SQL enthusiast loathe Schema duplication if it has SO many advantages? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I have a very similar load on my system. Read committed snapshot isolation did wonders for my deadlocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no enough information to advise.., but below should be considered:

- Snapshot isolation
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx
  Except when a database is being recovered, SNAPSHOT transactions do not request locks when reading data. SNAPSHOT transactions reading data do not block other transactions from writing data. Transactions writing data do not block SNAPSHOT transactions from reading data.
- Use transactional replication / log shipping / mirroring / Change Data Capture etc. to offload the main table
- Instead of deletion, soft deletion (update IsDeleted flag or maintaining xxxx_deleted table) is an option.

If the system (DB, hardware, network architecture) is properly designed, there are no issues even when where are thousands DML requests per second.

Comment: Interesting. After reading up it sounds like Read Committed Snapshot Isolation would definitely do the trick here as far as updates and selects go. 

But what about migrations? Eventually I'll have to offload some tasks to a new server. How would I know what temp tables to also port over? Seems really messy. 

The soft delete is a really interesting idea but you'd have to clear out the data at some point. Leaving too much dummy data in a table will just slow queries down eventually right?

Comment: re soft deletion:  yes, if you expect the high volume of deleted data, you can schedule a maintenance task that would physically delete the records in a loop (top 10K) over quiet time, e.g. weekend night.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. I like this answer. Good info. Thanks Anton

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server, if your tasks never touch rows that do not belong to them, you can try to use either optimistic or pessimistic versioning - [Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Depending on your situation, either Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) or Snapshot isolation level will do the trick. If both seem to suit you, I would recommend the former since it results in much less performance overhead.